# How to install Java 7 on Solaris 9?

Tags: solaris, jdk

Oracle states the following regarding Java 7:

> This version of the JDK is supported on the Oracle Solaris 10 Update 9
>   or later OS, Oracle Solaris 11 Express OS, and Oracle Solaris 11 OS

Unfortunately, I have Solaris 9 servers that can't be upgraded. Anyone knows of a workaround allowing to do this?

Comment: Have you tried building OpenJDK from source (see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html#solaris) or, if you don't specifically need Oracle Java, using/building IcedTea?

Comment: Thanks a lot, jaume. I didn't try to build from source, I will give it a chance. But don't you think it is risky if Oracle don't support it? and yes, I need Oracle Java...

Comment: Solaris 9 transitioned to extended support in Nov 2011, that's a long time ago and probably the reason why Oracle decided to drop support for it. As of your question: no, I don't think it is risky to use OpenJDK on Solaris 9. But it may be challenging to successfully compile it. Good luck!